# JavaFX Radio button disable/reenable text fields

Tags: java, javafx, scenebuilder

```
@FXML
private void isDelivery(ActionEvent event){
    if (rdDelivery.isArmed() == true){
        txtAddress.setDisable(true);
        txtEmail.setDisable(true);
    }
    else    {
        txtAddress.setDisable(true);
        txtEmail.setDisable(true);
    }
}
```

This code works to disable the text fields but after the first press they stay disabled and wont come back on when the radio button is pressed over and over.
So after first press the textfields become disabled permanently

Answer (score 3):

You got a typo in this logic:

```
if (rdDelivery.isArmed() == true){
    txtAddress.setDisable(true);
    txtEmail.setDisable(true);
}
```

Change to:

```
@FXML
private void isDelivery(ActionEvent event){
    txtAddress.setDisable(!rdDelivery.isArmed());
    txtEmail.setDisable(!rdDelivery.isArmed());
}
```

It's not clear from your post if you want these fields enabled when the radio button is selected, and not otherwise, so I assumed that the fields are *not* disabled when the radio button is selected.

No matter what, your logic says to disable those fields.

It might make things easier to use property binding to control the disabled state of your fields. If the radio button is checked, then you can enable the fields and if not, disable them using the `selectedProperty()` of the radio button.

Something like this (in your `initialize` method, or similar):

```
rdDelivery.selectedProperty().bind(Bindings.not(txtAddress.disabledProperty()));
rdDelivery.selectedProperty().bind(Bindings.not(txtEmail.disabledProperty()));
```

Comment: The fields are enabled by default and when i click the radio button it disables the fields like it should, but when the radio button is unchecked the text boxes remain disabled

Comment: @user206193 yes, you need to read the answer I posted. You have a flaw in your logic, where both the if/else blocks result in a `setDisabled(true)` call, no corresponding `setDisabled(false)` call. This results in the fields never being re-enabled. Fix that and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

You've written the code to disable them when it is checked, but you haven't done anything to handle when it is unchecked. You cannot expect the computer to infer this.

You need to listen for when the button is unchecked and respond appropriately.